# Bringing Static Site into RoR

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, stylesheet

I'm working on bringing a static site into a ruby on rails app so we can build out features, etc.

I've set up all the static pages with a pages controller and storing all the static pages under views/pages...

I already have CSS files that match up with each view (static page) and was wondering what the best way to bring these in are. A lot of the static pages have overlapping classes and ids so I don't want to just have one stylesheet for the application. I've looked over the asset pipeline but still confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give advice without more data about what your pages are...

But I suggest you to delete the Pages Controller and create controllers depending on their functions. If it's a login page then it should be, for example, handled by Login Controller.

Even if after doing that you still have 1 controller it's fine. It's just "pages controller" that's bugging me, because, trust me, if you are going to build features later it's going to be an irritating design. Simply because every controller is essentially a pages controller, so it's like creating a variable called "var".

After you have your controller set up create a few actions in it for each page where you want a unique stylesheet.

Rails allows you to create action-specific stylesheets, scripts and so on.

So now you are done. If you used rails constructors via console commands then you should already have a few empty .scss, .less or .css files associated with your actions/pages. You can freely change extensions too. If you don't want .scss then just change it to .css, it will work fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm getting empty .css files associated with each one of the views. Can you provide more instruction on how to do this and if I need to change anything in the application.css file